# setting set_minor_locator pyplot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, ticker

Hi all I'm discovering the wonderful world of matplotlib, in this context , I didn't figure out how to set the minor_locator .. or better which is the way in order to do it automatically , I'm going to explain the point :

this is a fragment of my code (I'm writing a class in order to define my plot style) 
in order to obtain the minor ticks in the way that I like I set :

```
         minorXLocator   = MultipleLocator(1)
         minorYLocator   = MultipleLocator(0.05)

         ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minorXLocator)
         ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(minorYLocator)
```

the aims of this fragment of code is to have 5 minor ticks between two major ticks (the ticks that have the number) I didn't find the way to automatize this ... is uncomfortable each time modify the value of MultipleLocator in order to get 5 minor ticks ...
May somebody light my way ?

**EDIT** sorry but I didn't got the point now I've tried to put =

```
majorLocator    = MultipleLocator(10)
minorXLocator   = MultipleLocator(majorLocator/5)
minorYLocator   = MultipleLocator(majorLocator/5)
```

but doesn't works it giveme back :

```
File "/home/marco/Programming/Python/Numeric/OdeSystem/makeplot.py", line 349, in plot
minorXLocator   = MultipleLocator(majorLocator/5)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'MultipleLocator' and 'int'
```

I was looking for a trick in order to automaticly put my `set_minor_locator` (the minor ticks) = 5 between 2 majorlocator (the ticks containing number)
like in the plot here [image: 5 minorticks between 2 major]

Comment: `MultipleLocator` creates ticks at multiples of the argument provided. So if you created the major ticks with a `MultipleLocator(N)`, you may use a `MultipleLocator(N/5)` for the minor ticks. Otherwise I'm not sure I understand the problem.